# Further chance of optimization of Thrust operation of CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a CUDA kernel which essentially looks like the following.

```
__global__ void myOpKernel(double *vals, double *data, int *nums, double *crit, int N, int K) {
  int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (index >= N) return;

  double _crit = crit[index];
  for (int i=0; i<nums[index]; i++) {
    double _res = vals[index*K + i];
    if (data[index*K + i] >= _crit) { _res = 0.0; }

    vals[index*K + i] = _res;
  }
}
```

This kernel evaluates `vals[N*K]` based on its `data[N*K]` compared to `crit[N]`, and the comparison is conducted on the first `nums[N]` elements of the `vals`'s segment (width K). If the `data` is smaller than `crit`, it leaves `vals` unchanged.

For example, data under consideration will look like the following

```
  int N = 3;
  int K = 5;

  vals[ 0] = 1.0; data[ 0] = 5.1; crit[0] = 5.0; nums[0] = 3;
  vals[ 1] = 1.0; data[ 1] = 4.9;
  vals[ 2] = 1.0; data[ 2] = 3.0;
  vals[ 3] = 0.0; data[ 3] = 0.0;
  vals[ 4] = 0.0; data[ 4] = 0.0;
  //-----------------------
  vals[ 5] = 1.0; data[ 5] = 2.9; crit[1] = 3.0; nums[1] = 2;
  vals[ 6] = 1.0; data[ 6] = 3.1;
  vals[ 7] = 0.0; data[ 7] = 0.0;
  vals[ 8] = 0.0; data[ 8] = 0.0;
  vals[ 9] = 0.0; data[ 9] = 0.0;
  //-----------------------
  vals[10] = 1.0; data[10] = 8.1; crit[2] = 9.0; nums[2] = 5;
  vals[11] = 1.0; data[11] = 7.8;
  vals[12] = 1.0; data[12] = 9.1;
  vals[13] = 1.0; data[13] = 200.;
  vals[14] = 1.0; data[14] = -1.0;
```

I noticed that this kind of operation is one of top 3 time-consuming kernels, and am considering Thrust-based acceleration.

What I came up with so far looks like the following. It uses `expand` provided on Thrust samples (https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/master/examples/expand.cu).

```
struct myOp : public thrust::unary_function<thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int,double>, double> {
                                        // vals   data   1/K 1%K nums crit
  __host__ __device__                   // 0      1      2   3   4    5
    double operator() (const thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int, double> &t) const {
      double res;

      if (thrust::get<2>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
        res = thrust::get<0>(t);  // do nothing
      }else {
        if (thrust::get<3>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
          res = thrust::get<0>(t); // do nothing
        }else {
          double tmp = thrust::get<0>(t);
          if (thrust::get<1>(t) >= thrust::get<5>(t)) { tmp = 0.0; }
          res = tmp;
        }
      }

      return res;
    }
};

int main() {

  using namespace thrust::placeholders;

  thrust::device_vector<double> vals(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> data(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit(N);
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums(N);

  thrust::device_vector<double> res(N*K);

  // ... fill values ...

  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums_expand(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit_expand(N*K);

  // 'expand()' does something like [1,2,3] -> [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         nums.begin(),
         nums_expand.begin());

  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         crit.begin(),
         crit_expand.begin());

  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.begin(),
                                              data.begin(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K), // index related to N
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K), // index related to K
                                              nums_expand.begin(),
                                              crit_expand.begin()),
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.end(),
                                              data.end(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K) + N*K,
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K) + N*K,
                                              nums_expand.end(),
                                              crit_expand.end()),
                    res.begin(),
                    myOp());

  ...

}
```

When I tried this with arbitrary values in the arrays with sets of `[N,K]` = `[1000,256]`, `[10000,256]`, `[50000,256]`, `[100000,256]`, already the performance is satisfactory.

[image]

But I wonder if there is any further chance of speed-up with my Thrust operations. I am expanding some values to take them into `if` statements, but maybe this can be avoided by `permutation_iterator` and so on, but I cannot come up with how. Also, I am doing `_1/K`, `_1%K` stuff to get the global and local index of the elements, which could be somehow avoided with more clever mind.

At least, for the cosmetics point of view, I would love to insert `expand(...)` into `thrust::transform(...)` directly without having to define another vector such as `nums_expand`.

Any suggestions for any chance of improvements are welcome.

***Full code used for the comparison***

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955505/can-thrust-transform-reduce-work-with-2-arrays%5B/url%5D

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
//#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#include <helper_timer.h>

/////////  https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/master/examples/expand.cu //////////
template <typename InputIterator1,
          typename InputIterator2,
          typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator expand(InputIterator1 first1,
                      InputIterator1 last1,
                      InputIterator2 first2,
                      OutputIterator output)
{
  typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<InputIterator1>::type difference_type;
  
  difference_type input_size  = thrust::distance(first1, last1);
  difference_type output_size = thrust::reduce(first1, last1);

  // scan the counts to obtain output offsets for each input element
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_offsets(input_size, 0);
  thrust::exclusive_scan(first1, last1, output_offsets.begin()); 

  // scatter the nonzero counts into their corresponding output positions
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_indices(output_size, 0);
  thrust::scatter_if
    (thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(0),
     thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(input_size),
     output_offsets.begin(),
     first1,
     output_indices.begin());

  // compute max-scan over the output indices, filling in the holes
  thrust::inclusive_scan
    (output_indices.begin(),
     output_indices.end(),
     output_indices.begin(),
     thrust::maximum<difference_type>());

  // gather input values according to index array (output = first2[output_indices])
  thrust::gather(output_indices.begin(),
                 output_indices.end(),
                 first2,
                 output);

  // return output + output_size
  thrust::advance(output, output_size);
  return output;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
void print_vector(T& vec) {
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << elem; 
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void printSdkTimer(StopWatchInterface **timer, int average) {
  float fAvgSeconds =
    ((float)1.0e-3 * (float)sdkGetTimerValue(timer) / (float)average);
  printf(" - Elapsed time: %.5f sec \n", fAvgSeconds);
}

struct myOp : public thrust::unary_function<thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int,double>, double> {
                                  // vals   data   1/K 1%K nums crit
  __host__ __device__             // 0      1      2   3   4    5
    double operator() (const thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int, double> &t) const {
      double res;

      if (thrust::get<2>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
        res = thrust::get<0>(t);  // do nothing
      }else {
        if (thrust::get<3>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
          res = thrust::get<0>(t); // do nothing
        }else {
          double tmp = thrust::get<0>(t);
          if (thrust::get<1>(t) >= thrust::get<5>(t)) { tmp = 0.0; }
          res = tmp;
        }
      }

      return res;
    }
};

__global__ void myOpKernel(double *vals, double *data, int *nums, double *crit, int N, int K) {
  int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (index >= N) return;

  double _crit = crit[index];
  for (int i=0; i<nums[index]; i++) {
    double _res = vals[index*K + i];
    if (data[index*K + i] >= _crit) { _res = 0.0; }  

    vals[index*K + i] = _res;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  using namespace thrust::placeholders;

  int N = atoi(argv[1]); 
  int K = atoi(argv[2]); 

  std::cout << "N " << N << " K " << K << std::endl;

  thrust::device_vector<double> vals(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> data(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit(N);
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums(N);

  thrust::device_vector<double> res(N*K);

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    crit[i] = 101.0; // arbitrary
    nums[i] = 200;   // arbitrary number less than 256
    for (int j=0; j<K; j++) {
      vals[i*K + j] = (double)(i*K + j); // arbitrary
      data[i*K + j] = (double)(i*K + j); // arbitrary
    }
  }

  // to be used for kernel
  thrust::device_vector<double> vals2 = vals;
  thrust::device_vector<double> data2 = data;
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit2 = crit;
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums2 = nums;

  StopWatchInterface *timer=NULL;
 
//--- 1) thrust
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums_expand(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit_expand(N*K);

  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         nums.begin(),
         nums_expand.begin());

  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         crit.begin(),
         crit_expand.begin());

  sdkCreateTimer(&timer);
  sdkStartTimer(&timer);

  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.begin(), 
                                              data.begin(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K), // for N
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K), // for K
                                              nums_expand.begin(),
                                              crit_expand.begin()),
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.end(), 
                                              data.end(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K) + N*K, 
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K) + N*K, 
                                              nums_expand.end(),
                                              crit_expand.end()),
                    res.begin(),
                    myOp());

  sdkStopTimer(&timer);
  printSdkTimer(&timer,1);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  sdkResetTimer(&timer);
  sdkStartTimer(&timer);

//--- 2) kernel
  double *raw_vals2 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vals2.data());
  double *raw_data2 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(data2.data());
  double *raw_crit2 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(crit2.data());
  int    *raw_nums2 = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(nums2.data());

  int Nthreads = 256;
  int Nblocks = (N*K - 1) / Nthreads + 1;
  myOpKernel<<<Nblocks,Nthreads>>>(raw_vals2, raw_data2, raw_nums2, raw_crit2, N, K);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  sdkStopTimer(&timer);
  printSdkTimer(&timer,1);

  sdkDeleteTimer(&timer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your own kernel is slow because of uncoalesced memory accesses.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor, I added the full code in the question. And yes, although I am aware of the concept of coalescing and have gone through Nvidia's developer posts that demonstrate it in the 3D FVM code, I have little idea on how can I do it with my kernel. Would it be possible without a significant change of the data structure?

Comment: Doing expand in Thrust is inefficient.There is an [efficient implementation by moderngpu 2.0](https://github.com/moderngpu/moderngpu/wiki/Load-balancing-search#interval-move-and-interval-expand). For more information about the topic, you can read below "From scan to load-balancing search" [here](https://moderngpu.github.io/intro.html) but this text uses the old moderngpu 1.0 API

Comment: You will have to use shared memory to cooperatively load the elements used by the block in a coalesced fashion. That is also what happens when using modergpu.

Comment: @paleonix, but the size limit of shared memory is 48kb, which translates to 6,000 doubles. If I have data whose segment width `K` is 256, then the threads I can handle in a block is 6000/256 = 23.4 which is smaller than the number of threads in a warp. Could you give me a little more comment how could I do it in my example?

Comment: I have seen kernels  that use the full block for global loads and stores, but then only compute with a single warp. If moderngpu works well for you, you might be able to learn more by looking at its implementation.

Comment: And the shared memory size limit can be higher depending on you actual GPU. You might need to configure more of the L1 cache to be used as shared memory and use dynamic shared memory.

Comment: @paleonix, indeed it's true. There is no better documents than the actual code written by experienced developers. Thanks for letting me know moderngpu. I was not even aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some modified benchmark code with improved kernels. Compiled with `nvcc --extended-lambda -arch=sm_89 -O3 main.cu -o main`

Since the timer is not included in your code, I use cudaEvents instead.
Data buffers are initialized in host vectors to avoid millions of memcopies.
I also noticed that the thrust approach does not produce identical results to your kernel for large N.

I added two kernels. `myOpKernel3` simply uses 1 threadblock per index to access the num[index] values.

`myOpKernel4` uses 1 thread per output element. this requires a prefix sum of nums, and the computation of `index` per thread. I chose to precompute the indices. An alternative approach would be to perform a binary search on the prefix sum within the kernel.

For full segments, i.e. nums[i] = 256, the output is

```
N 100000 K 256
expandtime 6.28806 ms
thrusttransformtime 1.05165 ms
myOpKerneltime 2.04301 ms
results from thrust and myOpKernel do not match
myOpKerneltime3 0.662016 ms
myOpKernel4_setuptime 0.723872 ms
myOpKerneltime4 0.785408 ms
```

For nums[i] = 128

```
N 100000 K 256
expandtime 6.2976 ms
thrusttransformtime 1.05472 ms
myOpKerneltime 1.04054 ms
results from thrust and myOpKernel do not match
myOpKerneltime3 0.337952 ms
myOpKernel4_setuptime 0.369152 ms
myOpKerneltime4 0.386048 ms
```

nums[i] = 4

```
N 100000 K 256
expandtime 6.2936 ms
thrusttransformtime 1.05165 ms
myOpKerneltime 0.273536 ms
results from thrust and myOpKernel do not match
myOpKerneltime3 0.119104 ms
myOpKernel4_setuptime 0.293824 ms
myOpKerneltime4 0.066848 ms
```

I did not test non-uniform segment sizes.
Note that performance costs of temporary memory allocations and thrust calls can be reduced by using custom allocators in conjunction with thrust's `thrust::cuda::par_nosync` execution policy.

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955505/can-thrust-transform-reduce-work-with-2-arrays%5B/url%5D

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>


/////////  https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/master/examples/expand.cu //////////
template <typename InputIterator1,
          typename InputIterator2,
          typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator expand(InputIterator1 first1,
                      InputIterator1 last1,
                      InputIterator2 first2,
                      OutputIterator output)
{
  typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<InputIterator1>::type difference_type;
  
  difference_type input_size  = thrust::distance(first1, last1);
  difference_type output_size = thrust::reduce(first1, last1);

  // scan the counts to obtain output offsets for each input element
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_offsets(input_size, 0);
  thrust::exclusive_scan(first1, last1, output_offsets.begin()); 

  // scatter the nonzero counts into their corresponding output positions
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_indices(output_size, 0);
  thrust::scatter_if
    (thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(0),
     thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(input_size),
     output_offsets.begin(),
     first1,
     output_indices.begin());

  // compute max-scan over the output indices, filling in the holes
  thrust::inclusive_scan
    (output_indices.begin(),
     output_indices.end(),
     output_indices.begin(),
     thrust::maximum<difference_type>());

  // gather input values according to index array (output = first2[output_indices])
  thrust::gather(output_indices.begin(),
                 output_indices.end(),
                 first2,
                 output);

  // return output + output_size
  thrust::advance(output, output_size);
  return output;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
void print_vector(T& vec) {
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << elem; 
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

struct myOp : public thrust::unary_function<thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int,double>, double> {
                                  // vals   data   1/K 1%K nums crit
  __host__ __device__             // 0      1      2   3   4    5
    double operator() (const thrust::tuple<double,double,int,int,int, double> &t) const {
      double res;

      if (thrust::get<2>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
        res = thrust::get<0>(t);  // do nothing
      }else {
        if (thrust::get<3>(t) >= thrust::get<4>(t)) {
          res = thrust::get<0>(t); // do nothing
        }else {
          double tmp = thrust::get<0>(t);
          if (thrust::get<1>(t) >= thrust::get<5>(t)) { tmp = 0.0; }
          res = tmp;
        }
      }

      return res;
    }
};

__global__ void myOpKernel(double *vals, double *data, int *nums, double *crit, int N, int K) {
  int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if (index >= N) return;

  double _crit = crit[index];
  for (int i=0; i<nums[index]; i++) {
    double _res = vals[index*K + i];
    if (data[index*K + i] >= _crit) { _res = 0.0; }  

    vals[index*K + i] = _res;
  }
}


  __global__ void myOpKernel3(
      double * __restrict__ vals, 
      const double * __restrict__ data, 
      const int * __restrict__ nums, 
      const double * __restrict__ crit, 
      int N, 
      int K
    ){
        for(int index = blockIdx.x; index < N; index += gridDim.x){   
            const double _crit = crit[index];
            const int num = nums[index];
            for(int i = threadIdx.x; i < num; i += blockDim.x){
                double _res = vals[index*K + i];
                if (data[index*K + i] >= _crit) { _res = 0.0; }          
                vals[index*K + i] = _res;
            }
        }
  }

  __global__ 
  void myOpKernel4(
    double * __restrict__ vals, 
    const double * __restrict__ data, 
    const int * __restrict__ nums, 
    const double * __restrict__ crit, 
    const int* __restrict__ numsPrefixSum,
    const int* __restrict__ indexForThread,
    int totalnums,
    int N, 
    int K
  ){
      const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
      const int numValid = totalnums;
      if(tid < numValid){
          const int index = indexForThread[tid];
          const int i = tid - numsPrefixSum[index];
          const double _crit = crit[index];
          double _res = vals[index*K + i];
            if (data[index*K + i] >= _crit) { _res = 0.0; }          
            vals[index*K + i] = _res;
      }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  using namespace thrust::placeholders;

  int N = atoi(argv[1]); 
  int K = atoi(argv[2]); 

  std::cout << "N " << N << " K " << K << std::endl;

  thrust::host_vector<double> h_vals(N*K);
  thrust::host_vector<double> h_data(N*K);
  thrust::host_vector<double> h_crit(N);
  thrust::host_vector<int>    h_nums(N);

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    h_crit[i] = 101.0; // arbitrary
    h_nums[i] = 4;   // arbitrary number less than 256
    for (int j=0; j<K; j++) {
        h_vals[i*K + j] = (double)(i*K + j); // arbitrary
        h_data[i*K + j] = (double)(i*K + j); // arbitrary
    }
  }

  thrust::device_vector<double> vals = h_vals;
  thrust::device_vector<double> data = h_data;
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit = h_crit;
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums = h_nums;

  thrust::device_vector<double> res(vals.size());



  cudaEvent_t eventA; cudaEventCreate(&eventA);
  cudaEvent_t eventB; cudaEventCreate(&eventB);
 
  //--- 1) thrust
  cudaEventRecord(eventA);
  thrust::device_vector<int>    nums_expand(N*K);
  thrust::device_vector<double> crit_expand(N*K);


  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         nums.begin(),
         nums_expand.begin());

  expand(thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K),
         thrust::constant_iterator<int>(K)+N,
         crit.begin(),
         crit_expand.begin());

  cudaEventRecord(eventB);
  cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
  float expandtime; cudaEventElapsedTime(&expandtime, eventA, eventB);
  std::cout << "expandtime " << expandtime << " ms\n";

  cudaEventRecord(eventA);

  thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.begin(), 
                                              data.begin(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K), // for N
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K), // for K
                                              nums_expand.begin(),
                                              crit_expand.begin()),
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(vals.end(), 
                                              data.end(),
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1/K) + N*K, 
                                              thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), _1%K) + N*K, 
                                              nums_expand.end(),
                                              crit_expand.end()),
                    res.begin(),
                    myOp());


cudaEventRecord(eventB);
cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
float thrusttransformtime; cudaEventElapsedTime(&thrusttransformtime, eventA, eventB);
std::cout << "thrusttransformtime " << thrusttransformtime << " ms\n";
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

//   std::cout << "vals after thrust\n";
//   for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++){
//     std::cout << res[i] << " ";
//   }
//   std::cout << "\n";


//--- 2) kernel
thrust::device_vector<double> vals2 = h_vals;
thrust::device_vector<double> data2 = h_data;
thrust::device_vector<double> crit2 = h_crit;
thrust::device_vector<int>    nums2 = h_nums;

  cudaEventRecord(eventA);

  int Nthreads = 256;
  int Nblocks = (N*K - 1) / Nthreads + 1;
  myOpKernel<<<Nblocks,Nthreads>>>(vals2.data().get(), data2.data().get(), nums2.data().get(), crit2.data().get(), N, K);

  cudaEventRecord(eventB);
cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
float myOpKerneltime; cudaEventElapsedTime(&myOpKerneltime, eventA, eventB);
std::cout << "myOpKerneltime " << myOpKerneltime << " ms\n";

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  if(res == vals2){
      std::cout << "results from thrust and myOpKernel match\n";
  }else{
    std::cout << "results from thrust and myOpKernel do not match\n";
  }


  

  {
    //1 block per index

    thrust::device_vector<double> vals_new = h_vals;
      thrust::device_vector<double> data_new = h_data;
      thrust::device_vector<double> crit_new = h_crit;
      thrust::device_vector<int>    nums_new = h_nums;

      cudaEventRecord(eventA);

      int Nthreads = 256;
      int Nblocks = N;
      myOpKernel3<<<Nblocks,Nthreads>>>(vals_new.data().get(), data_new.data().get(), nums_new.data().get(), crit_new.data().get(), N, K);

      cudaEventRecord(eventB);
      cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
      float myOpKerneltime3; cudaEventElapsedTime(&myOpKerneltime3, eventA, eventB);
      std::cout << "myOpKerneltime3 " << myOpKerneltime3 << " ms\n";

      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      assert(vals_new == vals2);
    }
      {
        //1 thread per output position
    
        thrust::device_vector<double> vals_new = h_vals;
          thrust::device_vector<double> data_new = h_data;
          thrust::device_vector<double> crit_new = h_crit;
          thrust::device_vector<int>    nums_new = h_nums;

          
          cudaEventRecord(eventA);
          thrust::device_vector<int> numsPrefixSum(N+1);
          numsPrefixSum[0] = 0;
          thrust::inclusive_scan(
              nums_new.begin(),
              nums_new.end(),
              numsPrefixSum.begin() + 1
            );
        const int totalNums = numsPrefixSum.back();
        thrust::device_vector<int> indexForThread(totalNums, 0);

          thrust::scatter_if(
                thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                thrust::make_counting_iterator(0) + N, 
                numsPrefixSum.begin(),
                thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                    nums_new.begin(), 
                    [] __host__ __device__ (int i){return i > 0;}
                ),
                indexForThread.begin()
            );
        
            thrust::inclusive_scan(
                indexForThread.begin(), 
                indexForThread.begin() + totalNums, 
                indexForThread.begin(), 
                thrust::maximum<int>{}
            );

          cudaEventRecord(eventB);
          cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
          float myOpKernel4_setuptime; cudaEventElapsedTime(&myOpKernel4_setuptime, eventA, eventB);
          std::cout << "myOpKernel4_setuptime " << myOpKernel4_setuptime << " ms\n";
    
          cudaEventRecord(eventA);
    
          int Nthreads = 256;
          int Nblocks = (totalNums + Nthreads - 1) / Nthreads;
          myOpKernel4<<<Nblocks,Nthreads>>>(
            vals_new.data().get(), 
            data_new.data().get(), 
            nums_new.data().get(), 
            crit_new.data().get(),
            numsPrefixSum.data().get(),
            indexForThread.data().get(),
            totalNums,
            N, 
            K
          );

          cudaEventRecord(eventB);
          cudaEventSynchronize(eventB);
          float myOpKerneltime4; cudaEventElapsedTime(&myOpKerneltime4, eventA, eventB);
          std::cout << "myOpKerneltime4 " << myOpKerneltime4 << " ms\n";
    
          cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
          assert(vals_new == vals2);
        }

  cudaEventDestroy(eventA);
  cudaEventDestroy(eventB);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and helpful answer. I was somehow convinced that `expand` would take almost no time. And yes, I had benchmarked Thrust and Kernel with only small N, and after reading your answer I took some time to inspect what had gone wrong to make such an difference between the two approaches, but I cannot spot the origin.. Anyway, thanks again for very helpful answers.

Comment: Ah, it was the very first `if` in the Thrust. As the index for `N`(i.e `_1/K`) goes beyond `nums`, everything is blocked at that `if`. That `if` shouldn't be there, I really cannot get why I put it there. Removing that `if` made the difference goes zero.